# Error Messages Generated When Destroying Old Window and Creating a new Window in Custom Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, destroy

Code successfully generates 'my_main' window with 2 buttons - 'Single' and 'Multiple'
Code successfully destroys 'my_main' when I click 'Multiple' button.

Code unsuccessful in creating 'my_multi' new window and generates errors listed at the bottom.

Can anyone help with this please?

This is the code:

```
##################################################
# Throw up our Main Window
##################################################

my_main = customtkinter.CTk()  # create a new window
my_main.geometry("1000x600")
my_main.title("Data Analysis Utility")

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

# Process Single File #


def button_click_singlefile():
    print("- You Selected Singe File")

button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(my_main, text="Process Single File", command=button_click_singlefile)
button1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)  # Put the button in a grid

# Process Multi File #

def button_click_multifile():
    print("- You Selected Multi File")
    my_main.destroy()  # Destroy the first window
    my_multi: CTk = customtkinter.CTk()  # create the Tk window like you normally do
    my_multi.geometry("1000x600")
    my_multi.title("Multi File Processing")
    button3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(my_main, text="new Multi")
    button3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)  # Put the button in a grid
    my_multi.mainloop()

# add widgets to the first window
button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(my_main, text="Process Multiple Files", command=button_click_multifile)
button2.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)  # Put the button in a grid

my_main.mainloop()
```

Code successfully generates 'my_main' window with 2 buttons - 'Single' and 'Multiple' Code successfully destroys 'my_main' when I click 'Multiple' button.

Code unsuccessful in creating 'my_multi' new window.

Following Errors are generated:

invalid command name "2887027264128update" while executing "2887027264128update" ("after" script) invalid command name "2887027257408check_dpi_scaling" while executing "2887027257408check_dpi_scaling" ("after" script) Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1892, in call return self.func(*args) File "C:\Users\maxim\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 553, in _clicked self.command() File "C:\Users\maxim\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Sleep Data Analysis Utility Weds 1.py", line 57, in button_click_multifile button3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(my_main, text="new Multi") File "C:\Users\maxim\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 52, in init super().init(master=master, bg_color=bg_color, width=width, height=height, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\maxim\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\core_widget_classes\ctk_base_class.py", line 41, in init tkinter.Frame.init(self, master=master, width=width, height=height, **pop_from_dict_by_set(kwargs, self.valid_tk_frame_attributes)) File "C:\Users\maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_init.py", line 3124, in init Widget.init(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra) File "C:\Users\maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_init.py", line 2572, in init self.tk.call( _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "frame" command: application has been destroyed invalid command name "2887027257152_click_animation" while executing "2887027257152_click_animation" ("after" script)

Comment: I don't know about this custom Tkinter, but in normal Tkinter this fails not because it can't create a new window, but because when you create `button3` it sends the command to the Tk object you just destroyed. You don't just create a window, but a module level Tk object / Tcl interpreter.

Comment: Thanks Emanual - I have this sorted now.